# Setting title of a button in UITableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

At first it looks easy, but my case is little different. I have a tableview with custom cell prototype containg a button. I am setting the title of the button based on my web response. My button is connected to view with outlet. Now on button click, I am opening an UIDatepicker, and picking the date from it. Now I have to set the selected date as title of my button. I am using a library for date picker, But you'll understand the code, cause the main problem is to set the date. I am not sure how to do it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

KKApproveCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"approve" forIndexPath:indexPath];


if (self.isRDDButtonClicked == NO) {

     cell.lineItemLbl.text = [[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]validatedValueForKey:@"lineItemNumber"];

    [cell.dateBtnOutlet setTitle:[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]validatedValueForKey:@"customerDeliveryDateAtSiteMax"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else
{

    NSLog(@"*******check date: %@, %ld",[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]valueForKey:@"requestedDeliveryDate"],(long)indexPath.row);

    cell.lineItemLbl.text = [[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]validatedValueForKey:@"lineItemNumber"];


    [cell.dateBtnOutlet setTitle:[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]validatedValueForKey:@"requestedDeliveryDate"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

[cell.dateBtnOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;

}

-(NSIndexPath *)getButtonIndexPath:(UIButton *)button
{
CGRect buttonFrame = [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:self.lineItemTableView];
return [self.lineItemTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonFrame.origin];
}

-(void)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"current row :%ld",(long)senderButton.tag);

//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"custList" sender:senderButton];

IQActionSheetPickerView *picker = [[IQActionSheetPickerView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date Picker" delegate:self];
//[picker setTag:6];
[picker setActionSheetPickerStyle:IQActionSheetPickerStyleDatePicker];
[picker show];

}
-(void)actionSheetPickerView:(IQActionSheetPickerView *)pickerView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    KKApproveCell *cell = [[KKApproveCell alloc]init];

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
 [cell.dateBtnOutlet setTitle:[formatter stringFromDate:date] forState:UIControlStateNormal];      
}
```

Comment: Not sure, if i´ve understand your question cause in -(void)actionSheetPickerView:(IQActionSheetPickerView *)pickerView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date the date should be set in the line  [cell.dateBtnOutlet setTitle:[formatter stringFromDate:date] forState:UIControlStateNormal];      
} Does´n´t it? Have u set a breakpoint there with the debugger? What is the context of [formatter stringFromDate:date]?

Comment: Yes, it should be. [formatter stringFromDate:date] is used to convert NSdate into NSString.

Comment: and this does not appear as the title of the button?

Comment: I help you.What problem do you face now?

Answer (score 0):

In your viewcontroller.h define string called _date

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *_date;
```

in your viewcontroller.m in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
check if it have value or not

```
if(__date=nil||__date.length==0)
{
[cell.dateBtnOutlet setTitle:[[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]validatedValueForKey:@"customerDeliveryDateAtSiteMax"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
[cell.dateBtnOutlet setTitle:__date forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

In your date picker method delegate set

```
__date=your date;
[_tableview reloaddata];
```

Comment: thanks ahmed, seems it would work. I'll update you after testing the code

Comment: Wouldn't it change the title of all button, I have to change the title of only that button which has clicked for datepicker.

Comment: @Xcoder use button.tag=index.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath and define parameter called _tag and set its value in picker method delegate and check it again it cellForRowAtIndexPath its very simple, just use tag.